# Groovy syntax highlighting in Vim 7.4

Tags: vim, groovy, syntax-highlighting

Since I updated Vim to version 7.4, Groovy syntax highlighting was broken.

For example:

```
int i1 = 100 / 2 * 5 + 120
```

In example above code after `/` char is highlighted as string literal while another `/` char will not be found there.

Is anyone met this error?

#### UPDATED:

1. Groovy regexp strings can be written as `/regexp/`, but in [official Groovy documentation](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Regular+Expressions) this string is not highlighted (I think because it is very difficult to separate this regexp and division expression).
2. In previous (7.3) major version of Vim is alright.

Comment: Report the bug, the mailing list is here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/vim_dev

Comment: Ok. Issue here https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/vim_dev/4m4FJGmkgb0

Comment: The question is answered in this topic -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26518938/vim-wrong-syntax-highlighting-in-groovy

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vim wrong syntax highlighting in Groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26518938/vim-wrong-syntax-highlighting-in-groovy)