# Vim wrong syntax highlighting in Groovy

Tags: vim, groovy, syntax-highlighting, vim-syntax-highlighting

when I do the single slash (`/`) when typing some arithmetic expression (like `val1 / val2`), my vim treats it as a comment for multiple lines (`/*`). The result looks like:

[image]

I now I can escape it by typing `;/` at the end of that line (which closes the comment), but it is still annoying and I'd like for my vim to behave properly :).

I've tried using another vim syntax highlighting package for groovy, I've tried `:filetype plugin off` in my .vimrc, I've tried purging vim with my settings and reinstalling it and the problem is still there.

Comment: I just checked in vim 7.3.762 and that's all ok. May be some plugin breaks highlighting.

Comment: You want `:filetype plugin indent on` in your vimrc. Does this happen with `vim -u NONE`?

Comment: and i can confirm with 7.4.273 - so it might be an regeression and you should report it.

Comment: at a very first glance it looks like it could be `4339:22fa3049e934` with changes to `groovyELExpr`, so vim now thinks the `/` starts a regexp.

Comment: @cfrick you're right :). that was the solution. don't know how to vote you up though :(

FDinoff, vim -u NONE did prevent the bug, but it also prevented any syntax highlighting :).

Comment: do you have a solution or a workaround right now?  then please add it as an answer.  you can (dunno, whep reputation is needed) upvote comments with the arrow right in front of the comment while hovering the comment with the mouse.

Comment: Yup, solution posted as an answer. Thanks a lot :). And yup, I guess it's something with reputation points, because I can't even see that arrow next to coments.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

As pointed out by @cfrick, vim (my version: 7.4) treats '/' as beginning of regular expression in groovy. The solution is to edit

```
/usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/groovy.vim
```

And around line 260-261 there is

```
syn region groovyString           start='/[^/]'  end='/' contains=groovySpecialChar,groovyRegexChar,groovyELExpr
```

Just change the start to

```
start='/[^*/]'
```

Edit: changed space in regexp to * as @calid suggested in comment below

<s>start='/[^ /]'</s>

(that is add the space there.)

And now it looks much better. On the other hand it will now not highlight regexps starting with space, but for me it's okay. At least it's much better than what it was.

This helped mi a lot with finding my solution:
[Groovy syntax highlighting in Vim 7.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18855809/groovy-syntax-highlighting-in-vim-7-4)

Comment: As already suggested in the referenced question, could you be bothered to report this?  As also other languages (like perl) share a syntax like this for regexp, there might be hope.

Comment: Yup, I reported it, the rest is now up to vim_dev and maybe in future versions it'll be solved on default.

Comment: Update - I sent an email to maintainer of groovy.vim syntax file, so hopefully in the next version it'll be solved

Comment: `/<space>` is perfectly valid for a groovy slashy string, really this should be changed to `'/[^*/]'` since `/*` is the multi-line comment start that currently breaks, and `/*` makes no sense as the start of a regex.

Comment: `'/[^ \*/]'` behaves best for me. It fixes not only the the division example given by the OP but it also one caused by HTML closing tags in documentation comments. It also highlights regex strings.